# Trouble shooting IR Sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor, infrared

I am trying to build a heart beat sensor. I implemented the application circuit suggested by the [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/82491/tsop382.pdf) of the sensor.

[image: Schematics]

But I get a constant reading at the Arduino. I confirmed that the IR emitter works using my phone's camera.

**EDIT**

I used 1uF in the actual circuit!

**EDIT**

I took the sensors from old disposed off electronics. And I was suggested that such sensors only detect signals that are modulated at ~4oKHz. The easiest solution is to use an IR Photoresistor. But I don't have an IR photoresistor. Will it detect it if I modulate the IR signal I send to that frequency? Will I still be able to work with the level of reflection?

Comment: I don't see a part number, I don't see a link to the datasheet. I don't see a question. What makes you think this circuit will work? Is it based on someone else's design? Link? Put all the information **in your question** and not in the comments. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar if you need it.

Comment: Are you modulating the LED?

Comment: NO... it is a continuous signal.. am concerned about the reflextion!

Comment: At this point you can choose between adding modulation to get a signal from your existing receiver and then stopping since it will not work for your project goal, or you can instead go get a suitable analog sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what parts you are using we can only make guesses.

That said, the fact that your receiver has a "data" output infers it is a remote control receiver. These are usually [integrated circuits with an IR sensor designed to receive IR signal modulated at about 40KHz](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay/TSOP4838/?qs=yGXpg7PJZCiwO12kec0Sug%3D%3D&gclid=CPXI2-Xp7swCFdgMgQodzw0ENA).  The output of such devices will either be high or low (presence or absence of the ~40KHz IR modulated signal).  Such a device wouldn't be suitable for detecting a range of IR radiation magnitude.

[Here](http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/files/capstone/capstone2014/Oximeter/Capstone-Report-29-Wearable-Pulse-Oximeter.pdf) is a (college) paper on designing a Pulse / Oxygen meter.  If you don't need the Oxygen part you can leave out one of the LEDs and what all goes with it.

Comment: Exactly. A ir remote receiver will ignore any signal not modulated at or near it's intended range. A basic Photodiode is typically used.

Comment: @Passerby - it's not that a receiver like this ignores any non-modulated signal, it's that the output is all-or-nothing.   A good way to make a low-noise analog system is to similarly modulate the transmitted signal, but then subtract the signal received when the modulation is off from the signal received when it is on, creating a lock-in amplifier.  That requires subtraction in the analog sense - ie, either with analog circuitry or after a suitable ADC.